# Finding non-word, non-space, and non-hyphen in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a pretty silly question, but for the life of me I can't figure out an easy way to do this in javascript.

If a string has "abcdefgh", this should return false (no error found)

but if a string has an invalid character like "@$$", it should return true (error found).

So, the general rule is if it contains a non-word, non-space, and non-hyphen, it should return true to indicate an error.

I tried `(/\W\D\S/).test('hello!')`, which should return true (found an problem) because of the "!", but it's returning false still.

Much appreciated!

Comment: FYI: the reason your own regex does not work is because it tests for "not a word character, not a digit, not a space" *in that order*. Also note that digits are also considered "word characters", so the `\D` is actually superfluous.

Comment: Thank you. I just learned something new today. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current regex, you're not looking for *any* of those things - you're looking for all three in a row.

Also, `\D` doesn't mean "non-hyphen", it means "not a digit".

You want to search for anything that doesn't match your whitelist:

```
(/[^\w\s\-]/).test('hello!')       // true
(/[^\w\s\-]/).test('hello')        // false
(/[^\w\s\-]/).test('hello-there')  // also false
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work `/[^\w\s-]/`
Returns true when line contains not any single non word, whitespace, or hyphen.

Comment: You guys rock. I'd upvote you if I could, but my rep level is too low. All I can do is thank you.